# Inline this scope 'binding'

Tags: javascript, scope, this, bind

I've a rookie question: I want to change 'this' context within a function by using 'bind' method, now... the widley spreaded covention for doing so is:

```
var bindedFetch = this.fetch.bind(this);
bindedFetch({
    error : function() {
        this.trigger('fetching-error', 'Data fetching error');
    }
});
```

but I want to achieve the same thing without using additional variables (I want to get the most clean code as possible) - so I've done something below:

```
this.fetch.bind(this, {
    error : function() {
        this.trigger('fetching-error', 'Data fetching error');
    }
})();
```

and it works... however I'm not convinced to this solution in 100%, has anyone some other advices on **how can I BIND and INVOKE a method in-line** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use bind if you are only going to use it once. Use call or apply instead.

```
returnFoo.call(context, arg1, arg2);
returnFoo.apply(context, [arg1, arg2]);
```

[See this blog](http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/invoking-javascript-functions-with-call-and-apply)

Comment: Plus you don't need to do bind/call/apply in your example!

Comment: Yes, ur ofcourse right... @LostInComputer - how so, why I don't need to bind/call/apply in here ?

Comment: actually for some reason the 'fetch' function changes the context for the 'window' object and I want to change 'this' context for the parent object as it supposed to be.